# Is there a way to do Monte Carlo Simulation for Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, testing, simulation

I'm a financial engineer student taking a blockchain technology electives. I recently also studied the Monte Carlo Simulation. I'm trying to see how we can use blockchain to do Monte Carlo Simulation. For now, the only method that I can think of is building thousands of different local blockchain in order to perform Monte Carlo Simulation on certain smart contract. However, this approach will be very hard to achieve. I am wondering if there is any other way that people can perform Monte Carlo Simulation to an on-chain smart contract?

Comment: What are you trying to simulate? The EVM isn't good at executing large or complex programs since you have to pay for every opcode execute, persistent storage is expensive, and transient memory is limited. For running large or complex programs there was some protocols like truebit to perform computations off-chain.